# Get list of fields in struct

Tags: clojure

How would I find what fields a struct has?  For example, if i have the following:

```
(defstruct bintree :data :left :right)
(def a (struct bintree 0 nil nil))
```

how would i get a list,set, or vector of (:data :left :right) from a?  I've tried

```
(show a)
```

but this gives no methods that look correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer - a simple

```
(keys a)
```

will get me this.